# Modem/router provided by ISP can only filter 6 MACs... what are some alternative implementations?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking, modem, isp

My ISP provided ZyXEL C3000Z router.  I'm trying to configure MAC filtering -- to permit only whitelisted addresses to connect.

After I added my 6th device (4 laptops -- 2 work issued, 2 personal, and 2 cell phones) I got this error:

> Reach Maximum MACFilter Number

I'm amazed at this... in this day of smart appliances (TVs, coffee makers, garage door openers, thermostats, etc.) multiple mobile devices, game consoles, etc., that 6 devices would be a limit.

Does anyone know of an alternative modem/router which is more capable than the one I currently have?

... or any other implementations?

What I am ***NOT*** looking for is to turn this into a security-related motherhood discussion.  Please don't reply with "MAC filtering isn't secure".  I already understand some of that.

Replies targeted to the information in this post are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just so you know, "[_MAC Whitelisting as well as Blacklisting are pretty much useless for security_](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/141745/141974)" and just becomes an administrative annoyance... It's amusing that the equipment can't do it properly, but I wouldn't recommend you look to do it in the first place. You understand "_some_" of the "_it's useless_", but want to do it anyway?

Comment: Does your router support RADIUS authentication? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS

Comment: @Attie... Just so you know, I did put in the post.... "Please don't reply with 'MAC filtering isn't secure'."  Thanks for completely disregarding the question as written.

Comment: @Andy .  It does not.  As I poke around the web interface more, I see this modem/router doesn't support much.  Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @MGoBlue93 no problem - if you wanted to know if it would have any performance implications, then ask about that directly... If you're looking for shopping recommendations, then you're off topic.

Comment: What is a “…security-related motherhood discussion.”?

Comment: @Attie... this is neither a question about MAC addresses not being encrypted nor is it a performance question and it's not a shopping question either.  Feel free to not reply any longer as all of *your* responses have been off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve assumed here that you are looking to provide a small modicum of protection against computer illiterate people accessing your Internet below.

---

Either get another ethernet router to sit between the Zyxel and your systems (I’d recommend something that can take DD-WRT and bypass this kind of MAC filtering crap) or find an alternative solution which does not use MAC address whitelisting.

One such solution might be to abandon DHCP and use static IPs hidden somewhere in the `10.0.0.0/8` network.

Alternatively—and it may not be possible on your router—use static DHCP assignments to handle valid systems/MAC addresses and assign out if a non-routed pool for everything else.

Comment: Just a comment: But are you feeling okay, @DavidGo? Your [typos here](https://superuser.com/posts/1442340/revisions) were pretty strange.

Comment: @jakegould Sorry. My cellphone keyboard is not great, and I must have forgotten to check for typos!

Comment: @JakeGould.... I was thinking about doing exactly that.  One of the reasons why I posted is I was wondering if that would have an effect upon performance.  Thanks!

Comment: Performance difference would not be perceivable unless you are a professional gamer - and even then probably not if you have decent hardware. My ASUS RT-AC68U increases latency by about 0.5ms. Throughput should not be affected either.

Comment: @MGoBlue93 I don’t post this answer. davidgo did.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your router/modem firmware has the latest update. When logged into router go to utilities tab/icon, 3rd one down is Upgrade Firmware.

When I got my C3000Z it was due for a firmware upgrade.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/965180)

Comment: @music2myear I interpret this answer as serious advice about upgrading the router, not as another irrelevant question.